# Batch request - 400 bad request response

Tags: gmail-api

I'm sending the following batch request for getting threads:

```
POST /batch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; type="application/http"; boundary="737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382"

access_token=accToken&quotaUser=user

--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <0x8d93fa0>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/threads/146df2dd11472f07 HTTP/1.1
Host: googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5


--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <0x8d93190>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/threads/146df14c9a13b5d9 HTTP/1.1
Host: googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5


--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <0x8d93190>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/threads/146def434891a5b0 HTTP/1.1
Host: googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5


--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <0x8d93190>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/threads/146def1dbfe6579c HTTP/1.1
Host: googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5


--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <0x8d93190>

GET /gmail/v1/users/me/threads/146def155ca0ab2b HTTP/1.1
Host: googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Magin (gzip)
Accept-Language: en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5
--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382--
```

However I get 400 bad request as a response from the Google servers: Request failed: bad request (400)

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

EDIT: interesting behavior: it works if there are <= 3 batched requests but if there are more it doesn't.

Comment: According to [the multipart spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), content before the first boundary and after the last boundary is ignored. It could be that your access_token and quotaUser parameters are being ignored, leading to an error. Are you using a library to create this message, or rolling it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

two things i notice:

(1) the space before the Content-Type on the first part

(2) missing a final "--737d0154-1999-455c-9886-65d7121a1382--" at the very end of the POST (on it's own line, etc), note the trailing "--" AFTER it the boundary as well...

Comment: Ahh, actually 1) and 2) are because of the StackOverflow formatting. (fixed that) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue and apparently having \r\n before the nested calls inside the batch request fixed it for me

ex:

--foo_bar
Content-Type: application/http

GET /v1/people:searchContacts?query=query&pageSize=100 HTTP/1.1
--foo_bar
Content-Type: application/http

GET /v1/otherContacts:search?query=a&pageSize=100&readMask=emailAddresses,names HTTP/1.1
--foo_bar
Content-Type: application/http

GET /v1/people:searchDirectoryPeople?query=query&pageSize=100&readMask=emailAddresses,names HTTP/1.1
--foo_bar--

Right before the GET has **\r\n** and not just **\n** or **\n\n**